# Why does threading sorting functions work slower than sequentially running them in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sorting

I'm new to threading in python (new to python actually). 
I cooked up a few sorting functions to test out python and thought it would be a good idea to run all three sorting algorithms in parallel for real time comparison. 
However, when I run the sort functions sequentially, the program takes less time than when I thread all three algorithms. Why does this happen? Isn't threading mean't to quicken things exactly like these?

```
import random
import time
import copy
import BubbleSort
import SelectionSort
import InsertionSort
import threading

# MAX contains the amount of numbers to sort
from MAX import MAX

def generateRandomList(List):
    """
    Generates a Random Usorted List
    """

    for i in range(MAX + 1):
        List.append(random.randrange(0, MAX + 1))

def displayList(List):
    """
    Displays a List until the first hundred values
    """

    for i in range(100):
        print List[i]

def isSorted(List):
    """
    Check if a List is sorted
    """

    for i in range(MAX):
        if List[i] > List[i + 1]:
            return False
    return True

def callSort(SortFunction, SortName):
    """
    Calls the function and records its execution time
    """

    StartTime = time.time()
    CopyList = copy.deepcopy(List)
    SortFunction(CopyList)
    Sorted = isSorted(CopyList)
    print ("%s Sort: %s seconds" % (SortName, time.time() - StartTime))
    print "IsSorted: ", Sorted
    print

class ThreadedSort(threading.Thread):
    """
    Class for running Sorting algorithms in a threaded fashion
    """

    def __init__(self, SortFunction, SortName):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.SortFunction = SortFunction
        self.SortName = SortName

    def run(self):
        callSort(self.SortFunction, self.SortName)

# Get the list
List = []
generateRandomList(List)

# Store sorting algorithms for easier access
SortFunctions = {
                    "Bubble" : BubbleSort.bubbleSort,
                    "Selection" : SelectionSort.selectionSort,
                    "Insertion" : InsertionSort.insertionSort
                }

# Store threads in a list
SortingList = []

""" Begin Sorting """

# Threaded Sorting
for SortType in SortFunctions:
    Sorting = threading.Thread(target = callSort, args = (SortFunctions[SortType], SortType))
    SortingList.append(Sorting)
    Sorting.start()

print "Threaded sorting has Begun..."
print
for Item in SortingList:
    print Item
print

"""
# Sequential 
print "Sequential sorting has Begun..."
print
for SortType in SortFunctions:
    callSort(SortFunctions[SortType], SortType)
"""

""" End - Sorting """
```

This is my code. Please help :)

Comment: Lock contention; pure-python code can't really run in parallel thanks to the Global Interpreter Lock. You are in essence still running the code sequentially but now with added overhead.

Comment: Would you mind explaining through the means of code. Like I said, I'm new to threading in general

Comment: Basically, any use of threads that doesn't involve I/O or C libraries that release the GIL is pointless on Python. This is a limitation of how the language has been implemented. Use multiprocessing instead here.

Comment: I'm reading up on it. Thanks a bunch :) Cheers!